# Title below Pie charts

Tags: reactjs, highcharts, pie-chart

We are using Highcharts in our UI. I need to have a title shown in the picture. Could you please tell me the way?[image]

Answer (score 0):

Set title `verticalAlign` property to `'bottom'`:

```
title: {
    text: 'Browser market shares in January, 2018',
    verticalAlign: 'bottom'
}
```

Live demo: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/cd2wyz3g/

API: https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/title.verticalAlign

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But, I need both texts ( "some text", "some more text") on 
 the single pie chart. Is there any way to do the same ?

Comment: To add the second text, you can use `subtitle` with `verticalAlign: 'middle'`. Please see this example: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/gfk25a48/

Comment: Thank you. Maybe the last question , how to fit the following with in pie? The text is in double quotation.

"xyz  abc defghi jkl mnopqrst"

Comment: Hi user2329702, What exactly do you mean? Could you present the problem in jsfiddle?